# Clicking on the inbox button several times opens it several times atop of each other

Tags: bug, user-interface, android-app

I do not think this behaviour was intended so I report it.

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3.

Comment: What version of Android are you running? I'm not able to reproduce this bug.

Comment: @jimsug 4.4.2. It seems a bit tricky to reproduce, I don't succeed all the time but I still manage to do it. You need to spam it fast before it has time to open, I usually end up keeping to click and eventually several open atop of each other. I got to click N times to close each and the background is progressively darker as the transparent backgrounds stack.

Comment: Unless I did it wrongly, I also couldn't repro it on Nexus 5, Lollipop 5.1.1, SE app 1.0.69. The inbox drawer only halt for a moment when I repeatedly press the button, but no subsequent darkening.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this on my Nexus 7.